# cmake: issue with target dependencies (add_dependency not working?)

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies

I have a small library gathering SCM info for each build. It has 2 targets:

1. `generate_scmversion_inc` a custom target running a script on every build, which generates a scmversion.inc file containing SCM info (label, date, time, etc.)
2. `scmversion` which compiles SCMVersion.cpp. This cpp file includes scmversion.inc.

On every build I want, in order:

- the script to run
- SCMVersion.cpp to rebuild

Towards this goal I declare `scmversion` to depend on `generate_scmversion_inc` with:

`add_dependencies(scmversion generate_scmversion_inc)`

Result:
`generate_scmversion_inc` runs every build as expected. But `scmversion` strangely only **every second time**. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I'm using CMake 3.4.3 with build system ninja 1.6.0

Code as reference:

```
project(scmversion)

set (SOURCES
     src/ndd/SCMVersion.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

add_custom_target(generate_scmversion_inc ALL 
                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
                          -DSOURCE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                          -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script/getscm.cmake)

add_dependencies(scmversion generate_scmversion)
```

Comment: Given your use case, I think you'd better go with [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_command.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working as intended by:

1. using a custom target `alwaysbuild` that is always built.
2. defining a `add_custom_command` with `BYPRODUCTS` option that is run on every build.
3. adding `alwaysbuild` as dependency to the project itself.

In code:

```
add_custom_target(alwaysbuild ALL)

add_custom_command(TARGET alwaysbuild
                   BYPRODUCTS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/scmversion.inc
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}  -DSOURCE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script/getscm.cmake)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} alwaysbuild)
```